# React: Comprobar si un dato se repite dentro de un map para poder ignorarlo

Tags: array, reactjs, map

Existe alguna manera de saber si un dato se repite dentro de un map? Por ejemplo:

```
  newArray = [name: "Jose", name:"Pedro", name:"Jose", name:"Ramon"]

  newArray.map((questmapn: any, index: any) => ({questmapn.name}))
```

Necesito saber si questmapn.name se repite dentro del bucle para crear un ternario que no me muestre los duplicados. Hay alguna manera simplificada?

Comment: ¿Cómo es qué `newArray` es un arreglo? Parece más un diccionario, con una sintaxis incorrecta. Ya que los diccionarios usan `{ }`.

Comment: @Jacobo el array está puesto a modo de planteamiento, no es correcto. Uso uno obtenido de un fetch. Servía para indicar lo que entiendo por "duplicado"

Comment: Entonces ponlo como un arreglo. No veo cual es la confusión en decir como generar un nuevo array ignorando los duplicados.

Comment: Si tienes un arreglo de objetos, entonces pon los objetos en tu código. Y específica que buscas eliminar duplicados de acuerdo a la propiedad nombre de cada objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder saber cuando tienes un duplicado o no, es bueno usar una estructura de datos de tipo `hash`. En este caso un `Set` es una buena opción para saber que objetos ya han sido agregados al arreglo. A diferencia de un arreglo, encontrar si un objeto esta en la estructura o no, tiene una complejidad de `O(1)`, por lo que es bastante rápido saber si algo esta o no. La desventaja es que ocupas memoria adicional.

Para resolver tu problema puedas usar un `Set` para solo agregar aquellos elementos que no estén aun en el `Set`. A su vez, para generar el arreglo deberás usar la función `filter` en lugar de la función `map`.

```
let set = new Set();
const names = ["Jose", "Pedro", "Jose", "Ramon"];

const newArray = names.filter((name) => {
    if (set.has(name))
        return false;

    set.add(name);
    return true;
})

console.log(newArray); // [ 'Jose', 'Pedro', 'Ramon' ]
```